# AngularJS invoke Controller function

Tags: angularjs

sorry for the rather basic question but I am really a beginner developing in AngularJS.
So I have a conteoller like this (like explaned here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide):

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('project.management')
    .controller('ManagementController', ManagementController);

function ManagementController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getUsersBySearchString= getUsersBySearchString;

    ////////////

    function getUsersBySearchString(searchString) {
        alert('get User By searchstring: ' + searchString);         
    }
};
})();
```

Now I have a HTML fragment in my template and I really don't know how to invoke function getUsersBySearchString(searchString). I have tried this one:

```
<div ng-controller="vm">
<form class="well form-search">
    <label>Usersuche:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="term" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Username">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="getUsersBySearchStringgetUsersBySearchString()">Suchen</button>
</form>
<pre ng-model="result">
{{result}}
</pre>
   </div>
```

but I don't know what to put here

```
<div ng-controller="vm">
```

and how to invoke the method.
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: `ng-controller="ManagementController as vm"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="vm">
```

That is incorrect. You have no controller named "vm". Your controller is named `ManagementController`.

The syntax for your use-case is

```
<div ng-controller="ManagementController as vm">
```

And to invoke the function, you would use

```
ng-click="vm.getUsersBySearchString(term)"
```

Note that the alias you choose in the HTML has no relationship with the alias you chose for `this`in the controller code. You might very well use

```
<div ng-controller="ManagementController as managementCtrl">
```

and

```
ng-click="managementCtrl.getUsersBySearchString(term)"
```